# What is "updating" in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) says:

> `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs

But I've noticed that `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked even a browser DOM element isn't updated.

So, what does the React Documentation mean by ***updating occurs***?

Comment: It's important to remember that the component and the DOM element aren't the same thing, just because the DOM doesn't change, the component may still have recieved updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"updating" is not DOM updates only but is part of the life cycle.
It occurs when there are new `props`, state updates and force updates

You can see this part in this diagram taken from the [DOCS](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's what I wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

componentDidUpdate is invoked when the render function within a component is called. This can happen when state or props changes. It can also happen when forceUpdate is called.

Sometimes, a component update may not trigger a DOM update. This is because React creates a virtual DOM after the update and checks with the virtual DOM before update. And only if there is a difference, the DOM is updated. In your case, probably, though the render function was triggered, there was no change in the virtual DOM and hence there was no DOM update.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments of the `componentDidUpdate` should satisfy your query. The `prevProps`, `prevState`, `snapshot` are those data that gets updated from some other hooks. And at that time, you'll need `componentDidUpdate` to handle the update.

This [picture](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) should give you detailed information on updates:

[image]

So, you can see `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs.

Answer (score 1):

componentDidUpdate will run if there are any STATE, or PROP changes made to the component after the initial render, whether or not the change is effecting the DOM.